# Two apt-get arguments to a docker run command doesn't work

Tags: docker

Using [this official Python image](https://registry.hub.docker.com/_/python/) I'm trying to supply a number of arguments with the `docker.run` command.

```
docker run -it --rm --name myserver -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp 
-w /usr/src/myapp python:3-slim apt-get update && apt-get install libpq-dev -y
```

First it shows the output of `apt-get update`, but then it returns:

```
apt-get: command not found
```

But somehow this properly outputs `START`, then the apt-get update output, and `NEXT` before throwing the error:

```
docker run -it --rm --name myserver -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp 
-w /usr/src/myapp python:3-slim echo "START" && apt-get -y update && echo "NEXT" && apt-get install libpq-dev -y
```

As if it cannot execute more than one `apt-get` command. Why does `echo` work, but the second `apt-get` not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to make sure those commands are executed in the docker context, you could tie them within a bash session:

```
docker run -it --rm --name myserver -v "$PWD":/usr/src/myapp \
-w /usr/src/myapp python:3-slim \ 
/bin/bash -xec 'apt-get update && apt-get install libpq-dev -y'
```

That way, the `&&` is interpreted by the *correct* shell (the one executed in the container), and not the one executing `docker run`.

But a better practice would be to define a new image with a new Dockerfile having those commands in `RUN` directives, in order to have a container with `libpq-dev` ready to be used.